# Trying to calculate the Expected Value of an observation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble and am trying to use values from two specific rows (Pinnacle book) to perform a calculation.  The values of the calculation will be written to a new column.  Here is the output of dput

```
structure(list(id = c("5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", "5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", 
"5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", "5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", 
"5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", "5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51"
), start = structure(c(1676691000, 1676691000, 1676691000, 1676691000, 
1676691000, 1676691000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), book = c("BetUS", "BetUS", "Bovada", "Bovada", "Pinnacle", 
"Pinnacle"), home = c("San José St Spartans", "San José St Spartans", 
"San José St Spartans", "San José St Spartans", "San José St Spartans", 
"San José St Spartans"), away = c("New Mexico Lobos", "New Mexico Lobos", 
"New Mexico Lobos", "New Mexico Lobos", "New Mexico Lobos", "New Mexico Lobos"
), team = c("San José St Spartans", "New Mexico Lobos", "San José St Spartans", 
"New Mexico Lobos", "San José St Spartans", "New Mexico Lobos"
), price = c(-140, 120, -140, 120, -138, 117), update = c("2023-02-18T00:24:43Z", 
"2023-02-18T00:24:43Z", "2023-02-18T00:25:10Z", "2023-02-18T00:25:10Z", 
"2023-02-18T00:25:04Z", "2023-02-18T00:25:04Z"), bep = c(0.58333, 
0.45455, 0.58333, 0.45455, 0.57983, 0.46083), no_vig = c(-128.33333, 
128.33333, -128.33333, 128.33333, -125.82353, 125.82353), no_vig_bep = c(0.56204, 
0.43796, 0.56204, 0.43796, 0.55718, 0.44282), win = c(71.43, 
120, 71.43, 120, 72.46, 117)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
id = c("5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", "5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", 
"5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", "5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", 
"5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51", "5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51"
), book = c("BetUS", "BetUS", "Bovada", "Bovada", "Pinnacle", 
"Pinnacle"), team = c("New Mexico Lobos", "San José St Spartans", 
"New Mexico Lobos", "San José St Spartans", "New Mexico Lobos", 
"San José St Spartans"), .rows = structure(list(2L, 1L, 
    4L, 3L, 6L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The following is the calculation

```
-4.482633 = (.55718 * 71.43) - (.44282 * 100)
```

The values in the calculation above correspond with the following variables

```
-4.482633 = Expected Value I am trying to derive
.55718 = "no_vig_bep" of Pinnacle
71.43 = "win" of observation 1
.44282 = 1 - "no_vig_bep" of Pinnacle or the last row
100 = a set amount
```

I Would then like to calculate the other side of the odds as follow

```
-2.5796 = (.44282 * 120.00) - (.55718 * 100)
```

The ultimate goal is to use the values of the Pinnacle book to perform the above calculation against all other books.  The EV will be written to a new column.

##### Included additional id for further clarification

```
structure(list(id = c("073c154f3c8586868a3ba21522161a70", 
"073c154f3c8586868a3ba21522161a70", 
"073c154f3c8586868a3ba21522161a70", "073c154f3c8586868a3ba21522161a70", 
"073c154f3c8586868a3ba21522161a70", "073c154f3c8586868a3ba21522161a70"
), book = c("Bovada", "Pinnacle", "MyBookie.ag", "MyBookie.ag", 
"Pinnacle", "Bovada"), home = c("Western Michigan Broncos", "Western 
Michigan Broncos", 
"Western Michigan Broncos", "Western Michigan Broncos", "Western 
Michigan Broncos", 
"Western Michigan Broncos"), away = c("Ball State Cardinals", 
"Ball State Cardinals", "Ball State Cardinals", "Ball State Cardinals", 
"Ball State Cardinals", "Ball State Cardinals"), team = c("Western 
Michigan Broncos", 
"Ball State Cardinals", "Western Michigan Broncos", "Ball State 
Cardinals", 
"Western Michigan Broncos", "Ball State Cardinals"), price = c(-185, 
-143, -142, 100, 108, 140), bep = c(0.64912, 0.58848, 0.58678, 
0.5, 0.48077, 0.41667), no_vig = c(-155.78947, -122.40329, -117.35537, 
117.35537, 122.40329, 155.78947), no_vig_bep = c(0.60905, 0.55037, 
0.53992, 0.46008, 0.44963, 0.39095), win = c(54.05, 69.93, 70.42, 
100, 108, 140), EV_1 = c(-15.2155015, -6.47562589999999, 
-6.20594459999999, 
-10.074, -6.47696000000001, 7.91119999999999)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = 
structure(list(
book = c("Bovada", "MyBookie.ag", "Pinnacle"), .rows = structure(list(
    c(1L, 6L), 3:4, c(2L, 5L)), ptype = integer(0), class = 
c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit1**: Maybe `purrr` can help you here:

```
library(purrr)
no_vig_pin_list <- df |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  split(df$id) |>  
  map(~.x |> filter(book == "Pinnacle") |> pull(no_vig_bep))

df |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  group_split(id) |> 
  purrr::map2_dfr(no_vig_pin_list, ~  .x |> 
               group_by(book) |> 
  mutate(EV_1 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 
                       (.y[1] * win)- ((1-.y[1])*100),
                       (.y[2] * win)- ((1-.y[2])*100)))) |> 
  select(EV_1)

 A tibble: 8 × 2
# Groups:   book [2]
  book      EV_1
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 BetUS    -5.03
2 BetUS    -1.10
3 Pinnacle -4.07
4 Pinnacle -4.07
5 BetUS    -4.48
6 BetUS    -2.58
7 Pinnacle -3.91
8 Pinnacle -3.91
```

Maybe this helps, I am not quite sure that I understood what you are trying to achieve.

```
library(dplyr)

no_vig_pin <- df |> 
  filter(book == "Pinnacle") |> 
  pull(no_vig_bep)

df |> 
  group_by(book) |> 
  mutate(EV_1 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 
                       (no_vig_pin[1] * win)- ((1-no_vig_pin[1])*100),
                       (no_vig_pin[2] * win)- ((1-no_vig_pin[2])*100))) |> 
  select(EV_1)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   book [3]
  book      EV_1
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 BetUS    -4.48
2 BetUS    -2.58
3 Bovada   -4.48
4 Bovada   -2.58
5 Pinnacle -3.91
6 Pinnacle -3.91
```

Comment: Yes, the math works for the above tibble.  I probably should've indicated that there are hundreds of different "id" observations.  If I add another id to the tibble, the math is off.  Standby, I'll share the actual dput of another tibble.

Comment: What is the trick to sharing another dput without exceeding the character limit?

Comment: I added new dput to the main post above.  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: At least I do not really get what you are trying to do, now your no_vig_bep variable contains four values for Pinnancle: 0.67035 0.32965 0.55718 0.44282. Which one do you want to use for which calculation exactly? Maybe could your post your expected output and some more clarification for the calculation steps.

Comment: That is correct.  There are now 4 Pinnacle values, 2 for each id.  I want to use the Pinnacle values for id 2168b3f2642fd7db9f4fabca39a2915c to perform calculations for books corresponding to that id.  I want to use the Pinnacle values for id 5d8f6b2536fbdc4ab6a3e9759ebc6c51 to perform calculations for books corresponding to that id.  I believe the solution lies with somehow grouping on Id and Book.  Make sense?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: Thank you @Julian.  This is what I was seeking!  I am relatively new with R and what you've provided is just above my level of expertise.  Thank you again!

Comment: @ Julian, would the arrangement of the data prevent the calculations from being accurate?  IE, do I have to arrange a certain variable(s) before executing your functions?  I have loaded a fresh set of data and the calculations aren't accurate.

Comment: the logic rests on my assumption that there are only two possible values for no_vig_pin for each id.

Comment: I think that is where the issue lies.  My example showed 2 books.  That is my fault for not indicating that there isn't a set number of id's and/or books.  In the real word there can be hundreds of id's and multiple books within each id.  Can we try one more example?  I will edit my original post.

Comment: So to further clarify.  There can be any number of id's.  The id represents an individual game.  Within each game there can be any number of books.  However, each book within each game will always have a pair of odds.

Comment: The order of the teams was throwing off the calculation.  After arranging by id, book, team I have no further calculation errors.  Thank you @Julian